# Promql join on different label names

Tags: promql

I need join to promql responses on label names.
I see good article - https://www.robustperception.io/left-joins-in-promql
And I see that on (foo) clause does mean a.foo = b.foo

Is it possible implement in promql a.foo = b.bar join?

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented by using label_replace for renaming label.

Comment: To rename a label, use `label_replace(metric, "new_label", "$1", "old_label", "(.*)"`

Comment: helpful, thank you. should make this an answer